# How to set a value as Double type use updateOne operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose schema:

```
const Double = require('@mongoosejs/double');

const Test = new mongoose.Schema({
  array: [{
    object: {
      value: Double
    }
  }]
});
```

Update query:

```
Test.updateOne({ name: 'abc' }, {
  $set: {
    array: [{ value: 1000 }]
  }
})
```

Actual: value is Int32

Expect: value is Double

When I use save a new data, it's Double. But update use $set, it's Int32

Answer (score 0):

If we define the array like `array:[value:{type:Double}]`, while saving whole numbers like `1 , 2 ...` the mongoose overrides the data type and saves the datatype as int32 rather than expected, because it is obvious that its datatype is int as double deals with floating point.

If you just want an array of values alone (not object), then you can try this :

Schema :

```
const Double = require("@mongoosejs/double");

const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  array: [Double],
});
```

Query :

```
let val = 5;
 await Test.updateOne(
    { name: "abc" },
    {
      $push: {
        array: val,
      },
    }
  );
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my schema is an object in array.